# Expectation of a product of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability

Given a sequence of Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$, if $X$ and $Y$ each denote the first time a success occurs and the first time a failure occurs, how can I get $E(XY)$? (So if $X=1$ then $Y$ must be greater than $1$, or if $X>1$ then $Y$ must equal $1$ etc)

I tried to solve it using the total expectation theorem but I was wondering if there is any better way to go about it.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Conditioning on the first trial, one gets $$E(XY)=p\left(1+\frac1q\right)+q\left(1+\frac1p\right)=\frac1{pq}-1$$

Comment: Well, as mentioned, *I conditioned on the first trial*. Does this ring any bell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either $X=1$ or $Y=1$.

\begin{align}
E[XY]&=E[XY|X=1]Pr(X=1)+E[XY|Y=1]Pr(Y=1)\\
&=E[Y|X=1]Pr(X=1)+E[X|Y=1]Pr(Y=1) \\
&=\left(1+\frac{1} q\right)p+\left(1+\frac{1} p\right)q\\
&=1+\frac{p} q+\frac{q}p\\
&= 1+\frac{p^2+q^2}{pq} \\
&= 1+\frac{(p+q)^2-2pq}{pq}\\
&=\frac{1}{pq}-1
\end{align}